# RoR: template missing error while rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the following code in my controller:

```
def tljson (result = [])
  @stat_id = params[:stat_id]
  @rpm = FedoraRpm.find_by_name(@stat_id)
  @rpm.ruby_gem.historical_gems.each { |h|
    result << { :content => h.version, :start => h.build_date }
    }
  @rpm.bugs.each { |b|
    result << { :content => b.name + "<br><a href='"+b.url+"'>View on BugZilla</a>", :start => b.bz_id }
  }
  @res = result.to_json
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render @res.to_json }
    end
end
```

Going to /tljson.json renders the JSON but the heading says 'Template is Missing; missing template'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to specify that you want to render `:json` in your `respond_to` block

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @res }
end
```

Otherwise it will look for a `tljson.json.erb` file.

Comment: You don't have to call `#to_json`.

Comment: I tried doing that, it returns this error:  SyntaxError in #tljson

stats_controller.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi, you don't tell what Ruby version you use, so answerer assumed that you use 1.9.x what is now stable and put in production. You must use 1.8 that is starting to be deprecated.

Comment: You'll have to add gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' if you're using Rails 4.1. Rails will warn you about this:
```The controller-level `respond_to' feature has been extracted to the `responders` gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature: gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.```